# How should I organize my Java banking system?

Tags: java, organization

I am having trouble wrapping my mind about how to organize my java banking system project. This is how I have the project set up so far:

```
v BankingSystem
-> JRE System Library
-v src
--v accounts
---> Account.java
---> BusinessCheckingAccount.java
---> BusinessSavingsAccount.java
---> CheckingAccount.java
---> PersonalCheckingAccount.java
---> PersonalSavingsAccount.java
---> SavingsAccount.java
---> StudentCheckingAccount.java
---> StudentSavingsAccount.java

--v banking
---> BankingSystem.java
---> Transaction.java

--v users
---> Address.java
---> Teller.java
---> User.java
```

Here's a picture if I didn't format that good: [image: java files]

Here's a description of the important classes for the project:

- A Teller is an employee of the bank and works directly with the banking system.
- A User is able to open a checking or savings account if they meet certain criteria.
- The BankingSystem should contain a HashMap used to map associated accounts to a
  user. It contains the core business logic of the application.
- An Account should contain fields for the unique id, primary account holder,
  authorized users, balance, date created, date closed, and the account status. The
  account status should be an enum for active, frozen, and closed.
- A Transaction is generated for each withdrawal or deposit on an account.
- A BankInformationDAO should exist to handle reading and writing to the database
  (file) when the program is initialized, each time an update occurs, and when the
  application exits. (I have no idea where to put this or what it is. Class, method?)

I am basically asking if this is a good way to store these files or not. I have no idea how this should all fit together. Just as a note, we will be adding a UI that this is all hooked up to, but we aren't that far yet.

ANY AND ALL help is appreciated. I feel so lost. This is for homework by the way so I'm only worried about the organization, not the names of the projects unless they clearly violate any common conventions.

Comment: Sounds like a better question for the Code Review SE.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That's what I inititally thought, but I wasn't sure because I didn't have any like.. actual code lol

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede if you think this would get more traction on code review though, let me know and I'll move it!

Answer (score 2):

Not comprehensive, but would be better to:

- use correct prefix for packages -> com.{companyName}...
- have layers separated clearly into packages (in your case all those classes should go into **model**; other layers would be controller, services, repositories...)

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiply approaches how to design your package structure.

Someone makes:

- model
- repository
- service
- ...

But I personally like a "Spring preferred way" - look Spring Pet clinic app and documentation. The main idea- separate by business object:

- security (model like User, repository UserRepository , controller UserController in the same package)
- savings (model, repository, controller in the same package)
  etc..

There is an another approach used by Adam Bien (google it):

- com.blah.**security**.***model***.User
- com.blah.**security**.***repository***.UserRepository